# бинарное дерево Java, метод clear()

Tags: java, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

Реализую бинарное дерево, и нужно переопределить метод clear(), который удалит все элементы из коллекции. Вопрос - правильно ли я делаю (пикча прикреплена)?
(надежда на сборщик мусора)
И если неправильно / не оптимально, то как лучше?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, правильно. Если на элемент нет ссылки, то сборщик сам устраняет его.

Comment: Даже если пробежаться по всему дереву и в каждой ноде установить null в качестве детей, то все равно дерево в памяти не станет занимать меньше места. Поэтому лучше отстрелить сразу голову и пусть gc дальше убирает.